# What is homebody economy?

Tags: markets

What is this thing named homebody economy? It seems to be related with the virus

It refers to working at home or maybe at online shopping?

Comment: I think a google search is probably what you should consider. It is not a term from the economic discipline.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about economics.

Answer (score 4):

A homebody is someone who doesn't leave their house much. The "homebody economy" refers to economic activities that do or do not do well when people tend to stay at home, which is exactly what is occurring now with the coronavirus pandemic.

Things like online shopping, media streaming services, or cook-at-home meal programs tend to do well when people are stuck at home. Things like movie theaters, restaurants, and cruise vacations require people be physically present, and do not do very well when people are stuck at home. The new "homebody economy" that's taken hold over the past few months is a result of people staying home due to the pandemic, and has had major, industry-specific impacts.